# Spring Security: manually added UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter triggers redirect after login

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, redirect, spring-security

I have started learning Spring Security. My intention is to develop a separate frontend that can interact with a Spring Web backend.

I am currently having some issues with Username/Password logins. In short, I am able to verify credentials, however I get a 403 Forbidden error. It seems that it is related to some behavior that redirects after the login.

Following is my current setup, which should be pretty simple:

In my authentication service `SecurityFilterChain` configuration I have disabled csrf protection and the default Spring Security form login page. At the same time, I allow requests to `/login` to allow to POST username and password:

```java
http.csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/error").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
```

After that in the same configuration I defined a simple Authentication Manager to check if the default Spring Username/Password filter works correctly. The filter is added to the Filter Chain as from what I've read during my research it seems that it isn't present by default if the login page is disabled.

```java
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter filter =
    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(authentication -> {
    String username = authentication.getPrincipal().toString();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

    if (username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Username or password not specified");
    }

    if (!username.equals("u") || !password.equals("p")) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Wrong username or password");
    }

    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null);
});

http.addFilter(filter);
```

Right now if I POST to `/login?username=u&password=p` I am getting 403 Forbidden as a response.

I have manually checked with a debugger line by line if the issue was inside the Authentication Manager, however with correct credentials it correctly returns the Username/Password Token.

I am not sure what I should expect after the Token is returned to the rest of the chain, however I've noticed by enabling log debugging is that it seems like the server is trying to redirect me, which is something that I'm not expecting at all.

Here's the debug log, which shows that at after the login a redirect is triggered:

```
[nio-8079-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /login?username=u&password=p
[nio-8079-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
[nio-8079-exec-3] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=u, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=false, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[]]
[nio-8079-exec-3] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8079/
[nio-8079-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=u, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=false, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[]]] to HttpSession [org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper$HttpSessionWrapper@7ba6bfb2]
[nio-8079-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=u, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=false, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[]]] to HttpSession [org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper$HttpSessionWrapper@7ba6bfb2]
[nio-8079-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
[nio-8079-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /
[nio-8079-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=u, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=false, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[]]]
[nio-8079-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=u, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=false, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[]]]
[nio-8079-exec-4] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Loaded matching saved request http://localhost:8079/
[nio-8079-exec-4] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to authenticate since no credentials provided
[nio-8079-exec-4] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8079/ to session
[nio-8079-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
[nio-8079-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
[nio-8079-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty SecurityContext
[nio-8079-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
[nio-8079-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
[nio-8079-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
[nio-8079-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
[nio-8079-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /error
[nio-8079-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
[nio-8079-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
[nio-8079-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

What can I do to stop Spring from redirecting my request after login?

Comment: First of all, NEVER send username and password as query parameters. It is HIGHLY unsecure. As the password will be logged in every internal system that uses http and not https. And it will be stored in the browser history etc.

Comment: It is trying to redirect you to `/` where you are suppose to deliver a webpage. Which you dont so you are then redirected to `/error` which is the default spring error page. If you are a beginner i recommend you implement `FormLogin` by reading the spring security docs and not jump into a custom sec solution which is in general bad practice

Comment: Thanks @Toerktumlare, I configured the FormLogin way and I managed to get it not to redirect. About sending username and password as parameters, do you have any suggestion for alternatives?

Comment: Passwords should always be sent in the body

Answer (score -1):

When the authentication succeeds, Spring Security tries to redirect you to `http://localhost:port/`, this `/` endpoint is secured because you configured `anyRequest().authenticated()`.

When you do `return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null);` in your implementation, that `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` constructor will set the user as [**NOT** authenticated](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/bf138c5154e87b55ab6f1c8940116351d6e1aedc/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.java#L55). In order to be authenticated, you have to [provide some authority](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/bf138c5154e87b55ab6f1c8940116351d6e1aedc/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.java#L72), like so: `return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, Set.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));` or even better `return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.authenticated(username, null, Set.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));`.

With that said, you should be using `formLogin` in this case, because what you are doing is essentially the same. When talking about security it's not recommended to write your own authentication mechanism if it's already written.